# Edit the Sidebar CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the sidebar to occupy the whole container, I'll give you a capture of what I'm looking for.

[image: here]

[This is the website.](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar)

Here you have the CSS Code for the Sidebars

```
/* sidebar */

.sidebar {
background-color:#fff;
padding:13px; 
margin: 20px;
margin-bottom:30px;
padding-bottom:20px;
color:#000;
}

.sidebartitle {
background-color:#000;
margin-left: -13px;
margin-right: -13px;
margin-top: -16px;
padding: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:22px;
text-align:left;
color:#fff;
}

#sidebar {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
        margin-left:15px;
    width: 340px;
        margin-top:20px;
}
```

And here you have the code for the posts

```
#contentmiddle {
    margin-left: 370px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
        width:650px;  
}

    .post {
padding:40px;
margin-top:60px;
background-color:#fff;
background-color:#fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
    }
```

This is the container

```
/* content */
#content {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#principal {  
width:940px;  
margin:0 auto;  
min-height:100%;  
height:100%;  
margin-top:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `width:100%;`. This will make the content fill it's container.

#### NOTE:

Does not work with `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

First off I would change more than this, but to just modify what you currently have to fill the space you would make these changes:

`.sidebar`'s margin to: `margin: 23px 0;` and padding to `padding: 13px 0;`

`.sidebartitle`'s margin to `margin: -16px 0 13px;`

remove `#content`'s padding

`#contentmiddle`'s width to `width: 715px;`

`.post` get rid of padding

`#contentmiddle h1` and `#postyapa` remove `margin-left` and `margin-right`

Then looks like this:

[image]